# Clear Bottom Of A Element

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS. My problem is how to clear the bottom of the div element width
text class to move the left-div-inside-span (child of main-span class) at the end of the transparent box?
These are the HTML and CSS codes I demonstrate below. I uploaded the output of the code in the image via a link. Please check them and show me a guide.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  border: 10px groove darkblue;
  background: powderblue;
  color: #9932CC;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  overflow: auto;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px double darkgreen;
  background: #3a768520;
  overflow: inherit;
}

div.header {
  background: #112244;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  border-top: 10px double crimson;
  border-bottom: 10px double crimson;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2%;
}

h1 {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 4px outset #fffbf9;
  display: flex;
}

h1::before {
  content: '\004f';
  color: #eee;
  background: dodgerblue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-decoration: underline #E9967A 2px;
  text-underline-offset: 0.4rem;
}

span.main-span {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  height: 65vh;
  background: #11464175;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-right: 10px double #f02a6cfd;
  overflow: auto;
  color: lightblue;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: cursive;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
}

span.text em {
  color: coral;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

div.main-flex {
  background: olive;
  width: 25%;
  height: 97.5%;
  border: 4px double #80000080;
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  display: flex;
}

div.main-flex>div {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

div.main-flex>div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: olive;
}

div.main-flex>div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: powderblue;
}

div.main-flex>div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: coral;
}

div.main-flex>div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: darkblue;
}

div.main-flex>div:nth-of-type(5) {
  background: darkred;
}

div.main-flex>div:nth-of-type(6) {
  background: darkorange;
}

span>div.left-div-inside-span {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
  margin-top: auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
  border: 4px double blueviolet;
  margin-right: auto;
}

span.main-span>span.text {
  background: rgb(58, 55, 21);
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Multiple Display Vlaues ...</h1>
</div>
<span class="main-span">
        <span class = "text">&#8212;This is a text inside&nbsp;<em>span</em>&nbsp;tag.</span>
<div class="left-div-inside-span"></div>
<div class="main-flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Please add a markup image of your desired result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't put divs inside spans.